# Replace part of fragment inside of FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentpageradapter, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter with several Fragments which are dynamically created during runtime depending on the user settings.

Depending on those user settings a part of each fragment should be replaced with another fragment (sometimes a progressbar should be added to the fragment, sometimes not).

This is my replacement code:

```
    OverviewProgressElementFragment fragment = new OverviewProgressElementFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.pBarContainer, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

The problem is, that this line `FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` causes this exception:

```
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877):     at com.xxx.xxx.OverviewEntityFragment.SetEntity(OverviewEntityFragment.java:119) <- the method in which I call the transaction
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877):     at com.xxx.xxx.PageAdapter.getItem(PageAdapter.java:27)
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
10-18 17:51:57.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1877):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
```

My hierachy is following:

1. MainActivity containing FragmentTabHost
2. One Tab containing ViewPager -> FragmentPagerAdapter -> Fragments
3. Fragments that should partly load 'Subfragment' dynamically

The error occures in Part 3 when a fragment trys to replace content.

Here is the creation-code of the fragment in my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    OverviewEntityFragment oeFragment = new OverviewEntityFragment();
    oeFragment.SetEntity(_entityList.get(position));
    return oeFragment;
}
```

The exception occures in the `SetEntity()`-Method. This is the code:

```
public void SetEntity(OverviewEntityData entityData)
{
_entityData = entityData;

 if ((_entityData.getEntityType() != ENTITY_TYPE.MEMORY)
 && (_entityData.getEntityType() != ENTITY_TYPE.NO_PAGE_FOUND))
 {
    OverviewProgressElementFragment fragment = new OverviewProgressElementFragment();
    fragment.SetEntityData(_entityData);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.pBarContainer, fragment);
    ft.commit();            
    }
}
```

The exception also occures when I just write:

```
public void SetEntity(OverviewEntityData entityData)
{
      FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
}
```

Is it not possible to replace parts of a fragment in such a hierachy or am I doing something wrong?

Any help is really appreciated.

***Edit:***

*I tried to use* `getChildFragmentManager()` *but this throws following exception:*

```
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1358)
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.xxx.xxx.OverviewEntityFragment.SetEntity(OverviewEntityFragment.java:121)
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.xxx.xxx.PageAdapter.getItem(PageAdapter.java:27)
10-18 19:02:48.622: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `FragmentActivity` you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

And in a nested `Fragment` call `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Edit:

When you create your fragment:

```
OverviewEntityFragment oeFragment = new OverviewEntityFragment();
```

This fragment is not yet attached to an `Activity`, hence the exception.

I'm guessing you could pass the `FragmentManager` to the `SetEntity()` method, but I'm not sure how that would work out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using getChildFragmentManager() inside my Fragment throws another exception. I updated my original post.